# Is it possible to vertically center a relatively positioned element?

Tags: css

I am trying to vertically center an image. I know how to do it with absolute position, but the problem with this is that other elements around it collapse into it.

This is how I vertically center using absolute position:

```
.element {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

I'd like to use relative position, but when I change absolute to relative, it does not work. Anyone have any suggestions to vertically center using relative position? I could do padding/margin top until its centered but I would like the css to generate it centered in case the image changes height when responsive.

This is the HTML and CSS, its pretty simple:

```
<div class="header-main-left">
    <img src="/images/header_logo.png" >
</div>

.header-main-left {
    float: left;
    height: 95px;
    position: relative;
}

.header-main-left img {
    position: absolute; //I want this to be position relative
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Please provide more code. What elements are around the elements you want to center?

Comment: I have another div to the right.

Comment: My general feeling for positioning cases like these is that you should be using flexbox.

Comment: Agreed, we need more code and you should probably use `flexbox`. But, you can do this: `div {position: relative; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 100vh;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position:relative` does not take an element out of the flow, it just allows you to change its render location relative to where it would've been rendered had it not been positioned.

`position:absolute` takes an element out of the document flow. This causes the elements origin to be the upper left of the nearest ancestor element that is not `position:static`.

If you need to set your particular element to `position:relative`, but need its initial position to be centered in its parent, add a wrapper element and move the centering to that wrapper.

```css
.header-main-left {
    float: left;
    height: 95px;
    position: relative;
}

.header-main-left .logo-wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    height:100%; /* let the relative top and transform on the img work */
}

.header-main-left img {
    position: relative; /* I want this to be position relative */
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="header-main-left">
  <div class="logo-wrapper">
    <img src="/images/header_logo.png" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the 
   display: table-cell;
Than the vertical align set to center

Or use tables.

Or use Jquery that add margin-top on the element equally to the half of its height